# Encoding in retrofit url with GET method

Tags: android, encoding, retrofit

I am not able to add special character "&" in my endpoint of the URL.
Here is my api interface

```
@GET("api/v1/products/artworks/")
    Call<TaskData> getLatestTaskData(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                     @Query("limit") Integer limit,
                                     @Query("offset") String offset);
```

URL that is getting called

```
artworks/?limit=50&offset=0%26ordering%3D-artwork
```

And this is how I am calling the api

```
String url = Integer.toString(totalitemsCalledLatest) +"&ordering="+ ordering;

                        Call<TaskData>

                            call = taskApiInterface.getLatestTaskData("Token "+ user_token, 50, url);
```

My ordering string is something like &medium=1&base=2
But it converts automatically & to %26 and = to %3D

Answer (score 0):

edit: assuming you are having connection problems to the api, i think you just need to remove the '/' from the end of your GET URL, like this: api/v1/products/artworks or at least that is one solution that will help you get closer to fixing your problem

Comment: Everything is correct in my GET URL, I just want to append the last parameter which has & and = sign but it is converting them into %26 and %3D respectively

Comment: can you please give me an example of what a correct request looks like?

Comment: my correct request looks like this   products/artworks/?limit=50&offset=0&ordering=-artwork

Comment: Retrofit converts string characters automatically, so if you are trying to have another query/parameter in your request, it's best to add that as a @Query like the rest of your arguments. so you'll have a 4th one for ordering

Comment: No man, my ordering string is something like &medium=1&base=2 where it converts & into %26 and = into %3D

Comment: oh ok. please excuse me, it looked like another query argument to me from the example you provided. As an alternative, you can try this:

`@Path(value = "your_string", encode = false)`

Reference:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html

note: just realized the docs are using the value `true`. I would try both ways to see which way is correct.

Comment: thanks for the answer but after trying everything possible including encode=false. did not work anything. I ended up using QueryMap which shortened my requirement because I wanted multiple keys for query but map doesn't take duplicate keys